# How I use user_id in another component

Tags: angular

How I use user_id in another component

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    public token: string;
    public user_id: string;

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by that?? do you want to share `user_id` value across various component..?

Comment: yes I want to pass the value of user_id in put method

Comment: update(user: User) {
        return this.http.put(this.loginUrl +user_id, user)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

Comment: There is no pub method in the code in your question and also no component where you want to use it. You can find all information in https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection and https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another component create instance of constructor and use it..

### constructor(){authenticationservice : Authenticationservice } this.authenticationservice.user_id;